# How to optimize a while loop which checks for datetime.time?

Tags: python, datetime

The following code is supposed to run every minute between 9:15am to 16:30pm.

```
while (datetime.datetime.strptime('09:15', '%H:%M').time()
           < datetime.datetime.now().time()
               < datetime.datetime.strptime('16:30', '%H:%M').time()):
    func 1
    func 2
    func 3
```

The functions take a total of 20-40 seconds. However by the end of day there is a lag of 1 minute. I have tested the functions inside and the problem doesn't seem to originate there.

Is there a way to make this `while` condition better/more optimized? Or am I looking in the wrong place, and the while loop might not be the culprit?

Comment: The amount of information you have provided is not enough to find the root cause of the problem. Just alone `while` condition will not increase the time from 40 sec to 1 min it has to be something with functions. Have you tried running while loop without the functions? Does the time lag increases? Are these functions are accessing something from memory which is increasing with time? One suggestion to put the calculation of boundary time values before the `while` loop.

Comment: Sounds like job for cron.

Comment: Could you post the ```func 1```, ```func 2``` and ```func 3``` you mention?

Comment: @KlausD. I am running it using cron. Would you suggest taking out the while loop and just running the script every minute from cron itself?

Comment: @anuragal, the functions access a sqlite database, I think that might be increasing the time. Do you think running it as I mentioned in the above comment would be better?

Comment: @S.L. unfortunately I can't, put they are using a combination of sqlite3 and pandas to make calculations.

Comment: I highly suspect that's where the issue is. Do you by any chance process an increasing amount of data throughout the day? I would suggest you profile time and memory usage. The code above looks solid otherwise.

Comment: you can time and log your functions and see when/where this lag takes place. maybe from there you'll see which function you need to improve.

Comment: @S.L. the amount of data being pulled is limited to 80000 rows at all times. The database is being written to by another script. I will profile the memory usage and time. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @EladL. I timed the functions, now doing a memory profile as suggested by SL.

Comment: You have written a busy loop that will run as many times as it possibly can between 09:15 and 16:30. Is that what you really want, or do you want it to run exactly once per minute. If the latter, you could use `time.sleep((-time.time())%60)` at the end of the loop to wait efficiently till the end of the minute before continuing. If you want to keep going as fast as possible to catch up when you fall behind, you could modify that sleep call to account for the difference between the current minute of the day and the number of times the loop has completed.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp Thanks a ton. I was doing something similar just after the while statement, but the logic was flawed. Your solution works perfectly. The fall behind aspect is something I will incorporate at a later date. Thanks.